# Scrollable layout in Android

Tags: android, forms, android-linearlayout

I have a registration form in a `LinearLayout` as shown below:

[image]

When emulator screen is in it's default position it is working fine. But when I rotate the emulator screen it only displays the elements which are fit to screen and remaining are wrap up. As shown in below screen:
[image]

Now I want to make this layout scrollable but not getting the idea. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Try putting your LinearLayout inside an ScrollView like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/menu_ll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks Fredrik, Actually I did also tried it before posting this question but because of some sort of problem's with Android Layout XML plugin it was not working.

Answer (score 0):

I simply added this code in my  activity of AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
```