# How to make a layout to be scrollable ? Android

Tags: android, layout, scrollable

Hi I am trying to create a layout which is going to contain a couple of image views a button and some text but the problem is that the layout is not scrollable. any idea of how I could implement that ? Many thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="204dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/pic11elit" android:contentDescription="ss"/>

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="whatever"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Reservation No :27210 10020"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
         <Button
    android:id="@+id/On_back"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="73dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="On_back"
    android:text="back" />
      </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scrollable layout in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202457/scrollable-layout-in-android)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try as below...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="204dp"
            android:contentDescription="ss"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="whatever"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Reservation No :27210 10020"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/On_back"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="73dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="On_back"
            android:text="back" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I am getting an error saying that scrollview can only host one direct child. any advice on how to fix that ? thanks for your reply!

Comment: @Nikolas...I have updated my answer...see the answer.

Comment: Hey sorry I just saw your comment I did upvote and accepted your answer. I have another question. Do you know how I could leave some space between the buttons and the textviews because everything is stretched and it doesn't really look nice. Any advice for that Sir ?

Comment: Hey sorry probably I miss clicked! Its ok thanks for your willing I just used relative layout instead of linear. Thanks sir.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a view called 'ScrollView'. Use this as your parent view.
Also keep these points in your mind :
 - A ScrollView is a [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html), meaning you should place one child in it containing the entire contents to scroll; this child may itself be a layout manager with a complex hierarchy of objects.
 - You should never use a ScrollView with a ListView, because ListView takes care of its own vertical scrolling. Most importantly, doing this defeats all of the important optimizations in ListView for dealing with large lists, since it effectively forces the ListView to display its entire list of items to fill up the infinite container supplied by ScrollView.
 - ScrollView only supports vertical scrolling. For horizontal scrolling, use HorizontalScrollView.

More can be find out here;
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

Answer (score 0):

Very simple. You have to use a scrollable layout. Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/foo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dude just add to your root layout a Scrollable VIew

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="204dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/pic11elit" android:contentDescription="ss"/>

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="whatever"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Reservation No :27210 10020"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
         <Button
    android:id="@+id/On_back"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="73dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="On_back"
    android:text="back" />
 </ScrollView>
      </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

ScrollView can have only one child! It will be OK to put your parent LinearLayout in ScrollView:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="204dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/pic11elit"
            android:contentDescription="ss" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="whatever"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Reservation No :27210 10020"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/On_back"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="73dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="On_back"
            android:text="back" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```